# What does Caliburn command not work when button content is changed?

Tags: silverlight, caliburn

Using Caliburn and Silverlight, I found that if I do:

```
            <Button PresentationFramework:Message.Attach="ContainerCommand InstructorProfileCommand()"
                    Height="60"
                    Content="Instructor" />
```

Then it works and the InstructorProfileCommand.Execute() method is called. However, if I do:

```
            <Button Height="60" >
                <Grid PresentationFramework:Message.Attach="ContainerCommand InstructorProfileCommand()">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="/App.Module;Component/Icons/navigate.jpg"
                           Height="50"
                           Width="50" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Instructor Profile"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                </Grid>
            </Button>
```

The Execute() command is not fired.
Is the attached property in the correct place for it to work?

JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that, in the second case, you should use the syntax:

```
PresentationFramework:Message.Attach="Event Click = ContainerCommand InstructorProfileCommand"
```

because if the trigger (Event Click) is not explicitly specified, the framework tries to infer it based on element the message is attached to.

Comment: Hola Marco. Unfortunately the above code does not load and gives an XAML parser error.

Comment: There's no Click event on Grid.  You would have to use a LeftMouseButtonUp

Answer (score 1):

Marco is correct.  However, I would move the attached property on to the Button as well.